Hasse invariant determine the isomorphism classes of its isometric groups
Let $F$ be a local field and consider $2n$-dimensional quadratic spaces over $F$.
Then the isometry classes of $2n$-dimensional quadratic spaces over $F$ are determined by its discriminant and Hasse invariant.
I am wondering whether two non-isometric $2n$-dimensional quadratic spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ with the same discriminant has the same isometry groups even though their Hasse invariants are different.
